# ECG Curve in javascript using some chart library

Tags: javascript, line, google-visualization

I want to simulate [ECG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocardiography) using javascript. i have done some part using JSXGraph using static point to show ECG curve, now the problem is i need to put a slider that will vary from 60 heart beats to 200 heart beats curve will compress or expand. so can you guys tell me some javascript chart library by which i can able to do this easily or some kind of link from where i can get information regarding this

Comment: yeah i know but g.raphaeljs but graph i am using right now is much powerful than g.raphaeljs i need some kind of equation,i know for making ECG curve they don't have equation but any previous that can help us in any ways thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are tring to do is modeling the ECG curve over time, try using [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series); it is a mathematical tool used to approximate periodic signals. Choose, say, 10 points on a given ECG curve, and calculate the 10 first [Fourier coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Fourier.27s_formula_for_2.CF.80-periodic_functions_using_sines_and_cosines). You should then have a rather accurate approximation of what you are trying to model.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this now i have made ecg curve but that with some constant point. i know little about Fourier Series thank you for your response

Comment: This can be a complex matter if you are not much into mathematics... Have you read the article I linked to? It explains the subject in details, my post is just about this particular application of Fourier series.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using gRaphael, though I'm not sure this will perfectly match your requirements.
http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Comment: yeah i know but g.raphaeljs but graph i am using right now is much powerful than g.raphaeljs i need some kind of equation,i know for making ECG curve they don't have equation but any previous that can help us in any ways thank you again

Comment: An equation is not more powerful than a library, they just are different things. You said you were looking for a JavaScript library.

Comment: yeah i know that my question was related to equation only but as there is no such equation for plotting ECG so i thought is somebody has already done this kind of work than may be that guy can help me in this